# xamarin forms custom font works in android but not in iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ww4K.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEsKS.png)

I added font and set build action and copy to...
add to Entitlement.plist
add to app.xaml style
and use it to my code

Comment: do NOT post code as images!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use custom fonts in iOS you have to add the Fonts to Info.plist instead of Entitlement.plist.

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>Fonts/YourFont.ttf</string>
</array>
```

**Update**
You can check out this tutorial from Johan Karlsson, he's integrating AwesomeFonts to Xamarin but thats the same as integrating any other font! Maybe this will help you.

http://www.johankarlsson.net/2015/10/fontawesome-using-xamarin-forms-and-ios.html

Comment: Thanks
I also change font name to real name of the font